# What does target stand for in AWS route table?

Tags: routing, aws

I am trying to understand properly how AWS routing works. I am looking at 
https://tutorialsdojo.com/aws-cheat-sheet-amazon-vpc/

Main route table

```
Destination   Target
172.31.0.0/16 local
0.0.0.0/0     igw-id
```

I understand the second line,that everyone can go to internet gateway.
But what does local stand for? Traffic goes where?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because AWS routing has nothing to do with Unix or Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the above example "local" means the VPC router will send traffic in that cidr range to the local VPC. Specifically, it will send the traffic to the specific network interface that has the IP address specified and drop the packet if nothing in your VPC has that IP address.

Also worth noting, is the local rule can't be overridden. The VPC router will ALWAYS route local VPC traffic to the VPC (and specifically route directly to the correct interface without letting anything else in the VPC have the ability to sniff it). That rule is provided mostly as a For-your-awareness rule. If you created a more specific rule such as 172.31.0.0/25, the VPC router would ignore it. In all other cases, the most specific route wins just like a normal router.

More broadly, the target can be a number of AWS resources that can accept network traffic:

#### Internet Gateways

The IGW is one-to-one NAT device that translates an instance's (or ENI's) private IP address into the public IP address assigned to it and sends it to/from the Public Internet. Due to its design, Instances without a public IP address cannot use the IGW, but they can use a...

#### NAT gateways

NAT Gateway as a target, so that instances will route to the NAT Gateway to get Internet access (note that this requires your instances be in a private subnet with a default route to the NAT gateway, and the NAT gateway be in a public subnet with a default route to the IGW.

#### Elastic Network Interface

This is a network interface attached to an EC2 Instance. If you wish to have a virtual IDS, web proxy, firewall, gateway, etc. that runs on EC2. You could set up a default route to that ENI. (again, you'll need to make sure your virtual gateway resides in a subnet with a different route table--one that has a default route to an IGW so that it doesn't route in circles).

#### Virtual Private Gateway

This device connects to a VPN or Direct Connect. It performs no address translation, so all communication over this device uses the VPC's private IP addresses

#### VPC Endpoint

This device connects directly to AWS API endpoints, so you can allow Instances without Internet Access to still reach the AWS API. Usually this is used to talk to s3. If the route's target is a VPC-E, the Destination should be the BGP prefix list of the AWS API endpoints (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59634064/s3-website-with-access-restricted-to-vpc-endpoint-is-getting-403-from-inside-the/59651374#59651374)).

#### Peering Connection

This device connects to other AWS VPCs, it uses VPC private IP addressing.